# How can I change the background color of an uneditable JTextPane in Java?

Tags: java, swing, background, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane` that has`pane.setEditable(false)` which forces it to have a 'greyed-out' background color.

After trying `setBackground(Color.WHITE)` (which doesn't work), I tried looking around the net for an answer but not managed to find one yet.

Can anyone help me on this one please?

Comment: Can you please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you?

Comment: I suggest checking [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1480217?start=0&tstart=0) link out. Hopefully it will answer your question

Comment: @Frakcool thanks, I began to write a Runnable Example and found the answer to the problem in doing so. I had `pane.setOpaque(false)` which was stopping me changing any colours on the pane. Thanks for the help. Sorry, I'm still learning alot about Java!

Comment: @ChrisMoran that's why, before asking a question here, you should prepare your MCVE or Runnable Example, most of times you find the solution while doing so :)

Comment: @Frakcool yeah sure, noted. Thanks for the help.I get a bit hasty and impatient sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what it was - it was because I had `pane.setOpaque(false)`, I couldn't change the background color without first either removing this or changing it to true.

`setBackground(Color.white)` worked after altering this.

Comment: Background color is different from what color to indicate disabledness of a component, I thought thats what you wanted originally.

Comment: I believe `setEnabled` and `setEditable` are two different things. I was inquiring about `setEditable`. I will keep your answer in mind if I ever need to alter components' colour with `setEnabled(false)`. Thanks

Comment: Ok got it. Didn't see that you used setEditable.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for some Look and Feel like Nimbus that don't respect background property, you can use this code :

```
private static class Painter extends javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter {
    private final Color color;

    private Painter(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    protected AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext getPaintContext() {
        return new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(null, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPaint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, 
            int width, int height, Object[] extendedCacheKeys) {
        g.setColor(c.isEnabled() ? c.getBackground() : color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

This defines a new custom painter for the background. For Nimbus, apply it to your JTextPane `jtp` this way:

```
        UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
        Painter painter = new Painter(color);
        String key = "TextPane[Disabled].backgroundPainter";
        defaults.put(key, painter);
        jtp.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
        jtp.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually try this one:

```
UIManager.put("TextPane.disabledBackground", Color.WHITE);
```

I think it should be `TextPane.disabledBackground`, if not try : `TextPane.inactiveBackground`

To change text back ground color I believe:
Try [setDisabledTextColor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDisabledTextColor(java.awt.Color)) on the pane.

Comment: Thanks for the input - however the issue is that I had was `pane.setOpqaue(false)` was stopping me from changing any color.