# Java Swing. Highlight background of whole line JTextPane using Style(not Highlighter class)

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, code-editor

How to Configure Style to make highlighting of whole line background. Like in most of IDE - current line background color is different to other code background.

Something like this:

```
private static final Style CURRENT_LINE = styleContext.addStyle("currentLine", defaultStyle);
static {
    StyleConstants.setBackground(CURRENT_LINE, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    StyleConstants.setEnd(Style.LINE_END); // This method does't exist!
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682076/2143488

Comment: @gohil90 Whis out using Highlighter class!

Comment: Probably [this topic](https://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/10862-how-select-highlight-entire-row-jtextpane.html) is what you want?

Comment: `Whis out using Highlighter class!` why? You use whatever class will get the job done. The current line will change as the caret moves from one line to another. A Style is meant to be used on a piece of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like in most of IDE - current line background color is different to other code background.

One way to do this is to use a custom `Painter`. The default `Painter` will only highlight the area containing the text on the line. So the custom painter will need to highlight the background from the start/end of the line.

The highlighting will need to change as the Caret moves from line to line.

Check out [Line Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/line-painter/) for a custom painter class that contains the above functionality.